# Trying to flip pose along x-axis does nothing

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I'm follow Sebastian Lague's RPG Graphics Tutorial for rigging and character animating (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFf5eGCjUUg&t=173s).  I've done everything up to weight painting except i've hit a road block when I noticed I couldn't flip a pose along the x axis.  Trying to Copy a pose and Paste a flip X-Pose does absolutely nothing.  However, I've noticed that if i select everything and then flip along the axis, it reverses everything along the x axis, but along both sides.

Before:
[image: Before A + Shift Ctrl V]

After:
[image]

I'm seriously stumped, I've followed all tutorials on here. Don't wanna go through all the weight painting over again :(

Blend Link: [image]

EDIT:  So i restarted blender and now it can reflect along x axis perfectly now?  I am very confused.  If someone can give an explanation, I would be love to learn why this fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your problem is the following one:

*Paste Pose Flipped* will paste the pose you've copied to the opposite side.

But let say you copy the left upper arm bone pose only, to paste flip it to the right upper arm bone. The problem is that the right upper arm is part of the right lower arm IK chain, so, whatever pose you’ll try to give it, it will obey to the lower arm IK's target. That's probably why you think sometimes paste flip doesn’t work.

If you select the left IK controller (called HandIK.L) and paste flip it, it will move the whole right arm, this time the copy paste flip is visible because you did it on a bone that controls and not obeys.

If you select all the bones and copy paste flip them, it will paste flip all the bones poses, so it will paste flip left IK controllers to the right side, and right IK controllers to the left side, and all other bones as well, it will completely invert the pose.

Comment: I would like to clarify that selecting all bones, then copying and x-flip pasting them, will not symmetrize the pose, but rather, will invert the pose. So if the right arm was up and the left down before the paste, the left arm will be up and the right will be down after the paste. Symmetrized would mean that either both arms would be up, or both arms would be down.

Comment: ok, corrected  ;)